# IIS 10.0 (Issues while Upgrade from Wind 2013 to Windows server 2022)

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, iis, windows-server-2022

We have some .Net code written in VS 2012 on Windows Server 2013. We are migrating to Windows Server 2022. We have upgraded to .Net framework 4.8 and have IIS 10.0 on Windows server 2022.

When we are trying to access any WCF services with .svc extensions, its not able to find the services and just saying Web Host failed to process a request. Exception System.Web.WebHttpException .svc does not exist.

Process Name: w3w-
ProcessID: 6128

Has anyone experienced this and does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

we looked into web.config files all look good, rebooted server, restarted app pools also made sure it has proper Authentication, reconfigured IIS. None of the options are working

Comment: When you say you "reconfigured IIS", what exactly did you do? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/deploying-an-internet-information-services-hosted-wcf-service#ensure-that-iis-aspnet-and-wcf-are-correctly-installed-and-registered WCF on Windows Server requires extra steps.

Comment: after running above command I get back :
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog, the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details.Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

Comment: You can enable includeExceptionDetailInFaults to get more responses for error messages.  Open the web.config file of the service and set includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" in the web.config file to include exception details. Database connections can also cause problems, please check the status of your database.